# Is MOSFET design inspired by biology and cells?

Tags: mosfet

Appears there are many similarities when it comes to Voltage-gated ion channels and MOSFETs.

“Voltage-gated ion channels are a class of transmembrane proteins that form ion channels that are activated by changes in the electrical membrane potential near the channel.”

“The functionality of voltage-gated ion channels is attributed to its three main discrete units: the voltage sensor, the pore or conducting pathway, and the gate.”

Is there any evidence that MOSFET was inspired by this?

[how do MOSFETS work](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/68831/how-do-mosfets-work)

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voltage-gated_ion_channel

Answer (score 9):

No, MOSFETs weren't inspired by cell biology.

MOSFETs were proposed in 1925.
Bipolar transistors were invented in 1947.
Voltage-gated ion channels were discovered in 1952.

Comment: That is interesting these very similar designs were all “discovered” relatively around the same time…

Comment: @P.S. Most of currently-known science was discovered within the last century, especially when it comes to microscopic things.

Comment: @P.S. The actual structure/function referenced in the question wasn't worked out until the 1980s, so not really discovered that close in time. In the 50s they just knew that some molecule(s) existed that let membranes responded to voltage, not what they were or how they worked.